# How can I call an exported function from itself?

Tags: javascript

how do I restart a Javascript function (node.js environment) from inside that has been declared like this:

```
exports.myfunction = function(parameter){
   //myfunction(); does not work
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "restart?" I will assume you mean to recursively call it. Have you tried this.myfunction() or even exports.myfunction() ?

Comment: Yes, I was talking about a recursive function call.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Name it](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/03/anonymouses-anonymous.html):

```
exports.myfunction = function myfunction(parameter) {
//                            ^^^^^^^^^^
    myfunction(); // does now work (but leads to a stack overflow obviously)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
exports.myfunction = function(parameter){
   exports.myfunction(); // this works
}
```